# Counting unique items in data frame

Tags: r

I want a simple count of the number of subjects in each condition of a study. The data look something like this:

```
subjectid  cond   obser variable
1234        1        1      12   
1234        1        2      14
2143        2        1      19
3456        1        1      12 
3456        1        2      14 
3456        1        3      13   

etc       etc    etc       etc
```

This is a large dataset and it is not always obvious how many unique subjects contribute to each condition, etc.

I have this in a data.frame.

What I want is something like

```
cond   ofSs 
1       122 
2        98
```

Where for each "condition" I get a count of the number of unique Ss contributing data to that condition. Seems like this should be painfully simple.

Comment: Thanks all. Well I was right that it was painfully simple. However, you all have taught me four ways of doing this and given me a better appreciation of some of R's many packages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `ddply` function from the `plyr` package:

```
require(plyr)
df <- data.frame(subjectid = sample(1:3,7,T), 
                 cond = sample(1:2,7,T), obser = sample(1:7))

> ddply(df, .(cond), summarize, NumSubs = length(unique(subjectid)))
  cond NumSubs
1    1       1
2    2       2
```

The `ddply` function "splits" the data-frame by the `cond` variable, and produces a summary column `NumSubs` for each sub-data-frame.

Answer (score 5):

Using your snippet of data that I loaded into object `dat`:

```
> dat
  subjectid cond obser variable
1      1234    1     1       12
2      1234    1     2       14
3      2143    2     1       19
4      3456    1     1       12
5      3456    1     2       14
6      3456    1     3       13
```

Then one way to do this is to use aggregate to count the unique `subjectid` (assuming that is what you meant by "Ss"???

```
> aggregate(subjectid ~ cond, data = dat, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
  cond subjectid
1    1         2
2    2         1
```

Answer (score 4):

or, if you like SQL and don't mind installing a package:

```
library(sqldf);
sqldf("select cond, count(distinct subjectid) from dat")
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to give you even more choice, you could also use `tapply`

```
tapply(a$subjectid, a$cond, function(x) length(unique(x)))
1 2 
2 1
```