# R finding number of unique records in a column

Tags: r, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Counting unique items in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459454/counting-unique-items-in-data-frame)

Hi my data includes same items multiple times in a column that is to say

Column A
a
b
c
a
a
c

yet the column has more than a million records.

How can I find the count of unique number of elements in the same column? Is there an easy way?

Thank you.

Comment: -1 A basic search of StackOverflow using the terms `r unique` would have led to a multitude of similar questions.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5459454/602276

Answer (score 9, accepted):

using the function...

> unique

Comment: sorry this is a dumb question. I should have looked this up in the help menu. thank you for your time.