# how to count distinct entries within a column of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am good with SQL and I naturaly use sqldf package.
However, it is useful to know native R way to achieve various SQL commands.

on a dataframe column, how can I achieve a similar count as in the last command?

```
library(ggplot2)
head(tips,3)
sqldf("select count(distinct day) from tips")
```

Comment: Seems a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459454/counting-unique-items-in-data-frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. I got little better now and can answer my own question.

```
d <- table(tips$day)
```

and then count how long is that list dim(d)