# Rule testing in R

Tags: r, rules, random-forest, sqldf

I have a set of rules that need to be tested. I am working with the iris dataset, and the rules generated are like  this:

Rule, Class

PetalLength > 2.45  AND  PetalWidth <= 1.7, versicolour
PetalWidth > 0.8  AND  PetalLength <= 4.75, versicolour

I want to now pass each rule through the dataset, and get a dataframe, where my rows are the records of the dataset, and the columns are the rules, and when each rule is passed through a record, if the rule classifies the record correctly, it gives a score of 1, else a score of 0 for that record, and these values are stored in the dataframe for each row. I wish to take a row sum after passing every rule, and if the row sum exceeds a certain value (say 3), then the passing of rules stops.

So far, I have written a code that runs each rule through the dataset, and gives me the number of instances that a specific rule has correctly classified, but I am not sure how to code this aspect. Can someone please help me out?

```
countfn <- function (x) {   
library(sqldf)   
return(print(sqldf(x)))}
dataset=iris
####The names alone are modified 
names(dataset) = c("SepalLength", "SepalWidth" , "PetalLength", "PetalWidth",  "Species")
####Reading the rules file to R 
rulefin = read.csv("FinalRules.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",",strip.white = TRUE) 
library(sqldf)
library(stringr)
####Query to see how many instances for a specific class are correctly classified by the rule
query=data.frame(paste('select count(*) from dataset where',rulefin$Rule,'  and Species
> =','\'',rulefin$Class),'\'',sep="")) 
library(data.table)
####Creating a table to store the number of correctly classified instances
df1=data.table(apply(query,1,countfn))
```

This code is getting me a data frame where each rule is run through all rows, and finally the column sum is given, i.e. the number of instances correctly classified by that specific rule.

Comment: Please take care in formatting your code. This is quite difficult to read.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry for the inconvenience caused. Hope this is fine now.

Comment: I also noted that I can use the ddply command from the plyr package to get a count based on a condition, from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459454/counting-unique-items-in-data-frame/5467845#5467845) but then the number of times a record is classified by the rules needs to be counted to use this.

Comment: Please provide a simple example with the expected output. Please clarify what you mean by "the passing of rules stops".